# Click and touch actions don't work in a React Native app Appium test via WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, webdriver-io

I starting to test a React Native app with Appium and Weddriver.io via the XCIUTest driver (documented [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest/) and [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#appium-xcuitest-driver)), initially on iOS targeting a simulator. It's early days: I've got the framework installed and running and set up an initial test - in which I want to click a T&C checkbox and then click a submit button on the initial welcome screen of my app. However neither the "click" nor the "touchAction" commands do anything - they don't trigger the onPress action callback or check the checkbox.

The component selectors are working OK, as I can query the "label" of the elements selected and they are correct (and if I purposefully break the accessibility id  I get errors). I can also write to an  field which I added for testing and I can change the text value to another string from the test, so I know I've got it generally set up and communicating with my app in the simulator OK.

I am targeting the BundleId of an already installed app (rather than a Zip to install which is another method).

So why might the click or touch actions not be triggering their behaviour?

Are there pitfalls around permissions, capabilities or security issues in Appium?

Should I be using "click" or "touch" in a React Native tests?

I am using React Native Base but I have replaced those UI components with simpler ones from React Native to remove that complication.

There is debug logging in the onPress callback, so if I click the button manually I see the logs, but commands from the Mocha tests don't log the attempt nor perform any actions.

Relevant package.json dependency versions:

```
dependencies:
    "native-base": "~3.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",

dev-dependencies:
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.10",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^8.0.1",
    "webdriverio": "^7.20.9"
```

I have Appium v8.5.5 installed globally, running in a terminal.

node: v16.15.0, npm: v8.5.5

I have tried many things, like waitForDisplayed, clicking the button before and/or after the successful input field text-entry, adding a  and clicking or touching that. I don't see any errors or warnings.

e.g. in my component (the checkbox and button are real, the input and link were added just for testing)

```
    async function onClickAgree() {
        console.log('HelpScreen.onClickAgree')
    }

...
                <Checkbox accessibilityLabel={ 'help_agree_checkbox' }
                          accessible={true}
                          isChecked={agree}
                          onChange={onChangeAgreeCheckbox}
                          value="agree"
                          label="Accept terms and conditions"
                          marginX="30"/>
                <Button accessibilityLabel={ 'help_agree_submit_button' }
                        accessible={true}
                        width={300}
                        onPress={() => onClickAgree()}
                        title="Get Started"
                >
                    Get Started
                </Button>
                <Link
                    accessibilityLabel="help_agree_test_link"
                    accessible={true}
                    onPress={onClickAgree}>
                    Test link
                </Link>
                <Input accessibilityLabel={ 'help_agree_test_input' }
                    accessible={true}
                    value={testInputContent} onChangeText={setTestInputContent} minWidth={200}></Input>
```

and in the test case:

```
import { remote } from 'webdriverio';

const opts = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        automationName: "XCUITest",
        platformName: "iOS",
        deviceName: "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
        platformVersion: "13.2",
        appPackage: "com.mydomain.myapp", // my app's bundleId
    }
}

describe('Initial test...', function (){
    let client;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        client = await remote(opts);
    });
    after(async function () {
        await client.deleteSession()
    })
    it('should do a test', async function () {

        const button = await client.$("~help_agree_submit_button")
        // await button.click()           // doesn't work!
        await button.touchAction('tap')   // doesn't work!
        await client.$("~help_agree_submit_button").click()// doesn't work!
        //
        // TODO: why don't any of the Tap/Clicks work??
        const link = await client.$("~help_agree_test_link")
        await link.click()             // doesn't work!
        await link.touchAction('tap')  // doesn't work!
        //
        const input = await client.$("~help_agree_test_input")
        await input.setValue('QA testing injection content') // works
        //
        await link.click()             // doesn't work!
        await link.touchAction('tap')  // doesn't work!
        //
        await input.setValue('QA2 testing injection content') // works!
        //
        await button.click()           // doesn't work!
        await button.touchAction('tap')// doesn't work!
        //
        const field = await client.$("~help_agree_checkbox")
        // await field.waitForClickable({ timeout: 3000 }) // no such method, webdriverio docs: not supported in native!
        await field.waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 3000 })
        // const field = await client.$("Checkbox");
        // const field = await client.$("ForwardRef(Checkbox)") // invalid but this is the name from the inspector
        await field.click()              // doesn't work
        await field.touchAction('tap')   // doesn't work...
...
```

The logs from the test runner show the Click and Touch commands being sent, and they seem similar to the successful POST for the input which works, so I can't see anything failing there.

```
2022-08-14T10:17:56.761Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:17:56.761Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
2022-08-14T10:17:56.935Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("accessibility id", "help_agree_test_link")
2022-08-14T10:17:56.935Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element
2022-08-14T10:17:56.935Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'accessibility id', value: 'help_agree_test_link' }
2022-08-14T10:17:57.033Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000',
  ELEMENT: '06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000'
}
2022-08-14T10:17:57.036Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:17:57.036Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
2022-08-14T10:17:57.287Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND touchPerform(<object>)
2022-08-14T10:17:57.287Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform
2022-08-14T10:17:57.287Z INFO webdriver: DATA { actions: [ { action: 'tap', options: [Object] } ] }
2022-08-14T10:17:58.007Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("accessibility id", "help_agree_test_input")
2022-08-14T10:17:58.007Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element
2022-08-14T10:17:58.007Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'accessibility id', value: 'help_agree_test_input' }
2022-08-14T10:17:58.180Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000',
  ELEMENT: '07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000'
}
2022-08-14T10:17:58.184Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClear("07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:17:58.184Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/clear
2022-08-14T10:17:58.283Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementSendKeys("07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000", "QA testing injection content")
2022-08-14T10:17:58.284Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value
2022-08-14T10:17:58.284Z INFO webdriver: DATA { text: 'QA testing injection content' }
2022-08-14T10:17:58.886Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:17:58.886Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/06010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
2022-08-14T10:18:01.500Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND touchPerform(<object>)
2022-08-14T10:18:01.501Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform
2022-08-14T10:18:01.501Z INFO webdriver: DATA { actions: [ { action: 'tap', options: [Object] } ] }
2022-08-14T10:18:01.823Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClear("07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:18:01.823Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/clear
2022-08-14T10:18:01.908Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementSendKeys("07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000", "QA2 testing injection content")
2022-08-14T10:18:01.909Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value
2022-08-14T10:18:01.909Z INFO webdriver: DATA { text: 'QA2 testing injection content' }
2022-08-14T10:18:02.506Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:18:02.507Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
2022-08-14T10:18:05.278Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND touchPerform(<object>)
2022-08-14T10:18:05.278Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform
2022-08-14T10:18:05.278Z INFO webdriver: DATA { actions: [ { action: 'tap', options: [Object] } ] }
2022-08-14T10:18:05.552Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("accessibility id", "help_agree_checkbox")
2022-08-14T10:18:05.552Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element
2022-08-14T10:18:05.552Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'accessibility id', value: 'help_agree_checkbox' }
2022-08-14T10:18:05.645Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000',
  ELEMENT: '03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000'
}
2022-08-14T10:18:05.649Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND isElementDisplayed("03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:18:05.649Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/displayed
2022-08-14T10:18:05.701Z INFO webdriver: RESULT true
2022-08-14T10:18:05.703Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:18:05.703Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
2022-08-14T10:18:05.874Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND touchPerform(<object>)
2022-08-14T10:18:05.874Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform
2022-08-14T10:18:05.874Z INFO webdriver: DATA { actions: [ { action: 'tap', options: [Object] } ] }
2022-08-14T10:18:06.154Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementAttribute("03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000", "label")
2022-08-14T10:18:06.154Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/attribute/label
2022-08-14T10:18:06.196Z INFO webdriver: RESULT help_agree_checkbox
label is  help_agree_checkbox
2022-08-14T10:18:06.197Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND isElementSelected("03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000")
2022-08-14T10:18:06.197Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/03010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/selected
2022-08-14T10:18:06.244Z INFO webdriver: RESULT false
```

The logs from the Appium server show similar POST traffic for both the click/touch and the successful input-edit, so I can't see an obvious failure point there. e.g."

```
[HTTP] {"text":"QA2 testing injection content"}
[debug] [W3C (11d60dce)] Calling AppiumDriver.setValue() with args: ["QA2 testing injection content","07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000","11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'setValue'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value' to command name 'setValue'
[debug] [Protocol Converter] Added 'text' property "QA2 testing injection content" to 'setValue' request body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value] with body: {"value":["Q","A","2"," ","t","e","s","t","i","n","g"," ","i","n","j","e","c","t","i","o","n"," ","c","o","n","t","e","n","t"],"text":"QA2 testing injection content"}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":null,"sessionId":"3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3"}
[debug] [W3C (11d60dce)] Responding to client with driver.setValue() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/07010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/value 200 595 ms - 14
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (11d60dce)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'proxyReqRes'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click' to command name 'click'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click] with body: {}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":null,"sessionId":"3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3"}
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3 with 11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/element/05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000/click 200 2768 ms - 65
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform
[HTTP] {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"element":"05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000"}}]}
[debug] [W3C (11d60dce)] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"tap","options":{"element":"05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000"}}],"11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'performTouch'
[debug] [XCUITest] Received the following touch action: tap(options={"element":"05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000"})
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wda/touch/perform] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3/wda/touch/perform] with body: {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"element":"05010000-0000-0000-8992-000000000000"}}]}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":null,"sessionId":"3D972CDD-B64A-4B57-ADCC-F2057E0C4DA3"}
[debug] [W3C (11d60dce)] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/11d60dce-5632-4800-a836-ca34623af0c1/touch/perform 200 271 ms - 14
[HTTP]
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the automation is clicking at the wrong co-ordinates.

I found there are additional logs you can enable to help debug.

`capabilities.showIOSLog`     streams iOS simulator debugging output,
which  goes into the Appium server logs.

`logLevel:debug` sets Webdriver to emit lower level logging which turns up in the Mocha test logs as additional "DEBUG" entries.

With these enabled I noticed a difference between the x,y position returned by the Appium/Webdriver [Get Element Rect()](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/rect/) or [Location()](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/location/) commands and the iOS XCSynthesizedEventRecord activity which is triggered by the [Click command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/click/).

```
Appium logs:

[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] <XCSynthesizedEventRecord 'tap'>
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Path 1:
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 542.5, 613.8, offset=0.00s


Mocha output:

/2E000000-0000-0000-67C7-000000000000/rect
2022-08-19T02:52:53.698Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 595, x: 487, width: 111, height: 38 }
```

Considering where the x,y is registered "X axis position of the top-left corner of the web element "  - W3C

So the button rect is  [595, 487] to [706,525]

So 542.5, 613.8 would miss it.

I finally got the click to register using this minimum offset. Interestingly clicking right on the x,y doesn't trigger it.

```
        client.touchPerform([
            { action: 'press', options: { x: rect.x+1, y: rect.y+1  }},
            { action: 'release' }
        ]);
```

Finally in my app console debug logs:

```
 LOG  HelpScreen.onClickAgree !!!!
```

So I still have the remaining problem of why or who is getting the coordinates wrong (e.g. XCUITest, iOS, React Native, React Native Base or my app layout), but at least I know what the problem is - and it's nothing to do with security, permissions or the test platform setup.