# Webdriver.IO getElementRect returns incorrect size for React Native button on iOS simulator

Tags: node.js, react-native, testing, webdriver-io, xcuitest

While [diagnosing a problem where Appium, Webdriver.io and XCUITest was clicking the wrong coordinates when calling `element.Click()` or `element.touchAction('tap')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350829/click-and-touch-actions-dont-work-in-a-react-native-app-appium-test-via-webdriv), I reduced my project down to the absolute minimum simplest example, excluding all UI libraries, dependencies and layout. The problem persisted, so I created a new template React Native app project, installed `webdriverio` and replaced the entire demo app screen with a single button.

Even in this simple example, the test framework clicks at the wrong location.

What happens is, while the button is sized at say 100,100 and appears to look correct on the screen in the simulator, when calling the `getElementRect` method I receive what seem to be the screen dimensions. Looking at the iOS debug, I can see it is also using these incorrect dimensions to click the centre of the button, so it misses the button entirely. If the button is made big enough to fill more than half the screen then the click works because it hits it. It's like the getElementRect API is just ignoring the actual size of the button.

How to reproduce:

Install a fresh React Native App (I'm on a Mac Monterey 12.2.1, using `nvm` with Node v16.15.0 and `rvm` with Ruby version v2.7.4 for installing Cocoapods etc)

`npx react-native init TestPositionApp`

Add the test platform to package.json dependencies, and run `npm i`

```
    "webdriverio": "^7.20.9",
    "mocha": "^8.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2"
```

Run pod install etc. as usual. Running any default simulator - for me it's the iPhone 13, but this doesn't seem to matter, I've tried several models. I have metro running in a terminal, and connected the chrome or IDE debugger.

I've installed Appium server and am running that with default settings.

`appium`

Add the following test to project/appium/test.js which locates a test button, retries its coordinates, then clicks it.

```
import {remote} from 'webdriverio';

const opts = {
  path: '/wd/hub',
  port: 4723,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  capabilities: {
    automationName: 'XCUITest',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    deviceName: 'iPhone 13',
    platformVersion: '15.5', // iOS version
    showIOSLog: true, // iOS logs go into the Appium server logs
  },
};

describe('Initial test...', function () {
  let client;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    client = await remote(opts);
    client.setImplicitTimeout(1000); // increase the implicit wait from 0
  });
  after(async function () {
    await client.deleteSession();
  });
  it('should do a test', async function () {
    // Wait for the page to arrive (after booting the app)
    const button = await client.$('~help_test1_button');
    await button.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 10000}); // wait for boot

    let location = await button.getLocation();
    console.debug('location', location);

    let size = await button.getSize();
    console.debug('size', size);

    let rect = await client.getElementRect(button.elementId);
    console.debug('rect', rect);
    await button.touchAction('tap');
  });
});
```

I have replaced the entire demo app with just this one button:

```
export default function App () {

  return (
    <Pressable
      accessible={true} accessibilityLabel="help_test1_button" testID="help_test1_button"
      style={{
        width: 200, height: 200,
        backgroundColor: '#789', borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 2, borderStyle: 'dashed',
      }}
      onPress={() => {console.debug('!! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!') }}>
      <Text>QA Button 1</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
```

This looks like this, as expected:
[image]

If I click it, I see the debug log in Chrome console as expected.

`!! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!`

If I run the test you can see that all three methods `getSize`, `getLocation`, `getElementRect` actually call the same underlying webdriver api `/rect`. But they all return `width: 844, height: 390` not the visible `width: 200, height: 200,`

`npx mocha appium`

```
2022-08-21T00:09:39.813Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
2022-08-21T00:09:39.871Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session
2022-08-21T00:09:39.871Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: {
      automationName: 'XCUITest',
      platformName: 'iOS',
      deviceName: 'iPhone 13',
      platformVersion: '15.5',
      showIOSLog: true
    },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: {
    automationName: 'XCUITest',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    deviceName: 'iPhone 13',
    platformVersion: '15.5',
    showIOSLog: true
  }
}
2022-08-21T00:09:42.089Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND setImplicitTimeout(1000)
2022-08-21T00:09:42.089Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/timeouts/implicit_wait
2022-08-21T00:09:42.090Z INFO webdriver: DATA { ms: 1000 }
2022-08-21T00:09:42.092Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("accessibility id", "help_test1_button")
2022-08-21T00:09:42.092Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/element
2022-08-21T00:09:42.092Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'accessibility id', value: 'help_test1_button' }
2022-08-21T00:09:42.153Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000',
  ELEMENT: '09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000'
}
2022-08-21T00:09:42.160Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND isElementDisplayed("09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000")
2022-08-21T00:09:42.160Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/element/09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000/displayed
2022-08-21T00:09:42.195Z INFO webdriver: RESULT true
2022-08-21T00:09:42.195Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementRect("09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000")
2022-08-21T00:09:42.196Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/element/09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000/rect
2022-08-21T00:09:42.225Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
location { y: 0, x: 0 }
2022-08-21T00:09:42.226Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementRect("09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000")
2022-08-21T00:09:42.226Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/element/09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000/rect
2022-08-21T00:09:42.250Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
size { width: 844, height: 390 }
2022-08-21T00:09:42.250Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getElementRect("09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000")
2022-08-21T00:09:42.251Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/element/09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000/rect
2022-08-21T00:09:42.281Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
rect { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
2022-08-21T00:09:42.282Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND touchPerform(<object>)
2022-08-21T00:09:42.282Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745/touch/perform
2022-08-21T00:09:42.282Z INFO webdriver: DATA { actions: [ { action: 'tap', options: [Object] } ] }
    ✓ should do a test (442ms)
2022-08-21T00:09:42.533Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
2022-08-21T00:09:42.534Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/fc3f7f73-a409-40a3-b6b5-5ab1db818745
```

The iOS logs show the rect being retrieved:

```
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.265 Df testmanagerd[19345:6d5f37] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Got snapshot for <AXUIElementRef 0x600003cd5800> {pid=36334} {uid=[ID:1 hash:0x0]}
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.266 Df testmanagerd[19345:6d5f37] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Got app orientation 0
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.266 Df testmanagerd[19345:6d5f37] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Captured accessibility snapshot data in 0.00s
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.266 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Checking 'TestPositionApp' for privileged AX value slot attributes
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.266 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Found main window: Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {844.0, 390.0}}
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.266 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Checking 'help_test1_button' for privileged AX value slot attributes
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.276 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Fetching AX parameterized attribute 91505, parameter (
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         Height = 390;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         Width = 844;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         X = 0;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         Y = 0;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     },
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     2253192071,
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     1
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] ) for Device system-wide element
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.276 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Decoded {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     Height = 390;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     Width = 844;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     X = 0;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     Y = 0;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] } to rect
```

And the iOS logs show the click happening at the centre of the [0,0]-[844, 390] rectangle, although the coordinates seem ordered y, x.

```
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.301 Df testmanagerd[19345:6d5f37] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Got app orientation 0
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.301 Df testmanagerd[19345:6d5f37] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Captured accessibility snapshot data in 0.00s
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.301 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Checking 'TestPositionApp' for privileged AX value slot attributes
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.301 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Found main window: Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {844.0, 390.0}}
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.301 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Checking 'help_test1_button' for privileged AX value slot attributes
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.311 Df TestPositionApp[36334:6f96f7] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Received attributes request for element: AX element pid: 36334, elementOrHash.elementID: 140669225028528.9. Attributes: (
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     "XC_kAXXCAttributeVisiblePoint"
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] )

...

[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.311 Df TestPositionApp[36334:6f7d0d] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Fetching AX attributes XC_kAXXCAttributeVisiblePoint for AX element pid: 36334, elementOrHash.elementID: 140669225028528.9
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.313 Df TestPositionApp[36334:6f7d0d] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Got attributes, transferring to dictionary for return.
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.313 Df TestPositionApp[36334:6f97ae] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Replying with attribute values: {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     "XC_kAXXCAttributeVisiblePoint" =     {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         X = 422;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         Y = 195;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     };
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] }
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.315 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Fetching AX parameterized attribute 91503, parameter (
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         X = 422;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]         Y = 195;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     },
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     2253192071,
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     1
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] ) for Device system-wide element
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] 2022-08-21 10:09:42.315 Df testmanagerd[19345:6f820f] [com.apple.dt.xctest:Default] Decoded {
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     X = 422;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]     Y = 195;
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] } to point

...

[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] <XCSynthesizedEventRecord 'Single-Finger Touch Action display 0'>
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Path 1:
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 195.0, 422.0, offset=0.00s
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch up at 195.0, 422.0, offset=0.10s.
```

and in this case, the button is not clicked, and there is no debug output.

However if I make the button big enough to actually fit into the above target (e.g. greater than 422 wide), the click hits it and it outputs the debug log.

Make the button 500 wide:

```
    <Pressable
      accessible={true} accessibilityLabel="help_test1_button" testID="help_test1_button"
      style={{
        width: 500, height: 200,
    ...
```

The webdriver reported Rect remains the same:

```
2022-08-21T00:24:56.904Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/abbd7daf-5e5b-4251-bf60-c4d1c27e8c94/element/09000000-0000-0000-EE8D-000000000000/rect
2022-08-21T00:24:56.932Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
rect { y: 0, x: 0, width: 844, height: 390 }
```

The iOS logs show the click is the same

```
IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] <XCSynthesizedEventRecord 'Single-Finger Touch Action display 0'>
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Path 1:
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 195.0, 422.0, offset=0.00s
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch up at 195.0, 422.0, offset=0.10s confirmed by TouchEventsCompleted.
```

`!! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!`

In my own app, I had another variant where the webdriver was returning the correct dimensions, but the iOS debug showed that XCUITest was doing something similar to the above. Also I found it varied with portrait vs. landscape orientations.

I can't see how I can have done anything wrong, as I've simply created a template app added one button and clicked in from a test, using all the defaults for everything.

Comment: I also found touchAction('tap') isn't the right syntax. It should be like: `browser.touchAction({action: 'tap',  x: 30,  y: 20})` and I now don't know where I got that example from originally.  
 https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/tap/

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions to the problem of the Rect of the Button/Pressable being wrong and seeming to expand to fill the parent view's rectangle:

1. adding a accessibilityLabel to the parent view
2. using a testID attribute instead of an accessibilityLabel

For example, I made a simple three-panel flexbox layout to explore the positions returned, moving it away from 0,0 to get better insight into the behaviour. I also stick to portrait for now, as I found the iOS-reported coordinates are spatially translated in other orientations which complicates things when debugging.

Here's an iPhone 13 with the 50x50 grey button just poking out of the speaker cutout (another complication of this orientation).

[image]

The entire app is simply this three views, with the button in the middle one:

```
export default function App() {
  return (<>
    <View
      style={{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      }}>
      <View
        flex={1/3}
        style={{
          height: 200,
          backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        }}
      ><Text>1</Text></View>
    <View
      // accessibilityLabel="help_test1_view"  // solution 1
      flex={1/3}
      style={{
        height: 200,
        backgroundColor: '#BDF',
      }}
    >
      <Pressable
        accessibilityLabel="help_test1_button" // remains in solution 1 only
        // testID="help_test1_button"          // solution 2
        style={{
          width: 50, height: 50,
          backgroundColor: '#789',
        }}
        onPress={() => {console.debug('!! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!') }}>
        <Text>QA Button 1</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
      <View
        flex={1/3}
        style={{
          height: 200,
          backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        }}
      ><Text>3</Text></View>
    </View>
    </>
  );
```

I ran the test on the various combinations

```
Button:        width: 50, height: 50,
Views:      ⅓, ⅓ , ⅓  = 130 each
Using:      await button.click()
Orientation:    Portrait Up
Button rect:    {x: 130, y: 0, w: 50, h: 50}
Expect click at [x:155, y:25] (button centre)

Using:      accessiblityLabel on Pressable
No accessibilityLabel on parent view.

2022-08-22T02:08:18.710Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 130, width: 130, height: 200 }
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 195.0, 100.0, offset=0.00s
onPress: NO, FAIL

With accessibilityLabel on parent view.

2022-08-22T02:14:07.629Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 130, width: 50, height: 50 }
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 131.0, 49.0, offset=0.00s
12:14:07.765 App.js:96 !! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!

Selecting:  TestID on Pressable
const button = await client.$('id:help_test1_button');
No accessibilityLabel on Pressable
No accessibilityLabel on parent view.

2022-08-22T02:17:56.346Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 130, width: 50, height: 50 }
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 131.0, 49.0, offset=0.00s
12:14:07.765 VM10 App.bundle:110 !! QA TEST 1 CLICK !!

Selecting:  TestID on Pressable
With accessibilityLabel on Pressable
No accessibilityLabel on parent view.

2022-08-22T02:34:19.206Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { y: 0, x: 130, width: 130, height: 200 }
[IOSSimulatorLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW]  Touch down at 195.0, 100.0, offset=0.00s
onPress: NO, FAIL
```

When using `accessibilityLabel` on the Pressable you need to add accessibilityLabel to its parent view too, then its `rect` is suddenly reported correctly. I found changing grandparents didn't affect it. I also found if they containing view has a border (I used for debug) this shifts all the coordinates by the same amount when the parent label is added. It feels like the "accessibility DOM" has its own independent layout space?

Alternatively using the `testID` alone solves the layout issue and removes the need for the parent label, but only if you remove the accessibilityLabel from the Pressable too. This is much simpler and was a nice surprise to discover.

I now realise the "strange" coordinates in the iOS logs were not wrong (other than when the above coords were also wrong), they just have a fairly complex behaviour. Firstly the point is translated in other device orientation rotations which I presume is because the origin remains in the same corner, but I confused myself and felt sleepy trying to run through the calculations. Secondly the `XC_kAXXCAttributeVisiblePoint` calculation seems far from simple: for example it helpfully avoids the cutout if possible, but tends to try to choose the centre of the component - but not always it seems. So I am saving my brain and ignoring them for now, solely relying on whether the onClick works or not to judge the solution.

I have opted for the `testID` solution as it was added in React Native 0.64 and there's *almost* no need to use the `accessibilityLabel` and suffer all the associated complexities it adds (by overlapping with real accessibility requirements across both iOS and Android). I found this article interesting: [An end to the abuse of Accessibility IDs](https://dev.to/nextlevelbeard/an-end-to-the-abuse-of-accessibility-ids-5d2j) .

However I have also found that some community components sadly haven't fully supported/wrapped `testID` properly or yet, e.g. [the React Native Base Checkbox component](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/4538), so sometimes I have to use the first solution.